# AWS Cloudformation conditionally add resource property

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation

I am expanding our cloudformation stack to a new region but wanted to enable encryption in our elasticsearch cluster.  However, I only want to enable it for new regions

I tried this:

```
Conditions:
  EnableEnhancedSecurity:
    !Not
      - !Equals
        - 'us-east-1'
        - { Ref: AWS::Region }

Resources:
  MyTestingElasticSearchStore:
    Type: "AWS::Elasticsearch::Domain"
    Properties:
      DomainName:
        Fn::Sub: 'stack-${AWS::Region}-${Stage}'
      ElasticsearchVersion: '7.1'
      ElasticsearchClusterConfig:
        EncryptionAtRestOptions:
            Enabled:
              !If
                - EnableEnhancedSecurity
                - 'true'
                - 'false'
          NodeToNodeEncryptionOptions:
            Enabled:
              !If
                - EnableEnhancedSecurity
                - 'true'
                - 'false'
         ...
```

but I'm getting the following error when I try to update my test stack:  `CloudFormation cannot update a stack when a custom-named resource requires replacing. Rename stack-us-west-1-test and update the stack again.`

I think this is because I'm adding the properties (even if they're, "false") So I'm trying to understand how I would conditionally add the properties.

I am trying:

```
Conditions:
  EnableEnhancedSecurity:
    !Not
      - !Equals
        - 'us-east-1'
        - { Ref: AWS::Region }

Resources:
  MyTestingElasticSearchStore:
    Type: "AWS::Elasticsearch::Domain"
    Properties:
      DomainName:
        Fn::Sub: 'stack-${AWS::Region}-${Stage}'
      ElasticsearchVersion: '7.1'
      ElasticsearchClusterConfig:
         ...
      Fn::If:  # only add the properties if needed
        - EnableEnhancedSecurity
        -
          EncryptionAtRestOptions:
            Enabled: 'true'
          NodeToNodeEncryptionOptions:
            Enabled: 'true'
       - { Ref: AWS::NoValue }
```

but am running into the following error:

```
YAML Errors:
while parsing a block mapping
  in "<unicode string>", line 76, column 5:
        Type: "AWS::Elasticsearch::Domain"
        ^
expected <block end>, but found '<block sequence start>'
  in "<unicode string>", line 148, column 6:
         - { Ref: AWS::NoValue }
```

Is this even possible?  if so, how do I even set this up in just the new regions without touching the existing one via cloudformation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error happens because **you provided name** for your domain using `DomainName`. From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-elasticsearch-domain.html#cfn-elasticsearch-domain-domainname):

> **If you specify a name, you** **cannot perform updates that require replacement** of this resource. You can perform updates that require no or some interruption. If you must replace the resource, specify a new name.

Both `EncryptionAtRestOptions` and `EncryptionAtRestOptions` **require replacement**. This means that since you used `DomainName`, you can't modify these properties.

You would have to tear down the current ES domain, and recreate it without `DomainName` for replacement updates to be possible. You can rename the domain to do it as well if you want to use different `DomainName` which will also delete existing ES domain and create new one.

**Update regarding conditions**

You should be able achieve what you want using the following syntax:

```
Resources:
  MyTestingElasticSearchStore:
    Type: "AWS::Elasticsearch::Domain"
    Properties:
      DomainName:
        Fn::Sub: 'stack-${AWS::Region}-${Stage}'
      ElasticsearchVersion: '7.1'
      ElasticsearchClusterConfig:
      EnableEnhancedSecurity:
        Fn::If: 
          - EnableEnhancedSecurity
          - { Enabled: 'true' }
          - !Ref "AWS::NoValue"
      EncryptionAtRestOptions:
        Fn::If: 
          - EnableEnhancedSecurity
          - { Enabled: 'true' }
          - !Ref "AWS::NoValue"
```

Comment: As I said, "I am expanding our cloudformation stack to a new region but wanted to enable encryption in our elasticsearch cluster. However, I only want to enable it for new regions"

My question is about conditionally adding the properties, not about the particular error.

Comment: @simpleCoder So why did you quote this error? Its confusing. So you have two issues in your question?

Comment: @simpleCoder I updated the answer for the issue with syntax. Please have a look.

Comment: Yep, I tried your updated suggestion and it work!   I think the key part I was missing was to move the Fn::If above the "Enabled" attribute of the property.